# Динамическое обновление QListWidget через QComboBox

Tags: python, pyqt5

У меня есть заполненные QComboBox и QListWidget. Записи в QListWidget привязаны параметром к записям в QCombobox. 
Как мне динамически изменять список в QListWidget при выборе новой записи в  QComboBox.
В частности как мне передать событие из QComboBox в QListWidget о том что запись в QComboBox изменилась.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте сигнал изменения параметров `QComboBox`. Если я правильно понял ваш вопрос.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QListWidget, QComboBox, QApplication, \
                            QHBoxLayout
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt

class MyListWidget(QListWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    def sortItems(self, order):
        QListWidget.sortItems(self, getattr(Qt, order))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    window = QWidget()
    lay = QHBoxLayout()

    box = QComboBox()
    box.addItem('AscendingOrder')
    box.addItem('DescendingOrder')


    lst = MyListWidget()
    lst.addItems(map(str, range(8)))

    box.currentIndexChanged[str].connect(lst.sortItems)
    # в данном случае сигнал, порождаемый событием изменения выбранного
    # элемента в `box`, присоединяется к обработчику, принадлежащему
    # обьекту `lst` 

    lay.addWidget(box)
    lay.addWidget(lst)

    window.setLayout(lay)

    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Спасибо. В итоге я пришел к такому же решению.